# Kinetic kame on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ros, installation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys.
I'm a newbie in the ROS world and i have to install it.
Following this guideline: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu.
when i reach the point 1.6 and i execute this:

`echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc source ~/.bashrc`

i get this "error":
bash: source/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory

Any advice to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance

P.S. i'm also newbie on Linux, so i have to learn quickly a lot of stuff

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291151/kinetic-kame-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts/) by [lolito](https://answers.ros.org/users/35164/lolito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:
Did you run that all in one command? Because those are at least two separate commands: one starting with `echo` and the other with `source`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nope, i run them separately...anyway i redo the ubuntu installation and then the ROS installation all works fine.
In any case thanks a lot for the feedback! :)
only one more question: is there a link(website) where i can learn, maybe through a tutorial, the main features of turtlesim?

---

Originally posted by [lolito](https://answers.ros.org/users/35164/lolito/) with karma: 16 on 2018-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-15**:
re: turtlesim: that would probably be [wiki/turtlesim/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim/Tutorials).